# Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> occurred

Tags: xamarin.android

How can I solve this problem? Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class  occurred

این کد من هست آیا مشکلی داره؟

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1.3" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:background="@mipmap/v1" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1.3" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:background="@mipmap/v2" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1.3" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout6" >
         <TextView android:text="لایه ها:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="#ff000000" android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" >
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout7" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:background="@mipmap/v3" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout8" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:background="@mipmap/v4" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout9" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView5" android:background="@mipmap/v5" />
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150dp" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" >
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout10" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView6" android:background="@mipmap/v6" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout11" >
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView7" android:background="@mipmap/v7" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:minWidth="25px" android:minHeight="25px" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout12" android:background="@mipmap/v8">
         <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView8" />
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What type are your files (v1~v8)?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided and found that if remove these lines:

```xml
android:background="@mipmap/v1~v8" />
```

It will work well.